# Win32 Tab Control w/Multiple Rows

Tags: c++, winapi, tabs

I have a tab control in my Win32 application. The control is multi-row capable. When I resize the window such that the tab control is reduced in width, multiple rows show up. The problem is that when I click on one of the lower rows the tabs in the upper rows are blocked by the current tab's window( the tab control doesn't properly resize the content window of the current tab so that the upper rows are visible ). How do I account for this problem?

Here is code for my resize function:

```
RECT cr;
    GetClientRect( pHdr->hWndTab, &cr );
    TabCtrl_AdjustRect( pHdr->hWndTab, FALSE, &cr ); 
    OffsetRect( &cr, cxMargin - cr.left, cyMargin - cr.top );
    SetWindowPos( pHdr->hWndDisplay, 0, cr.left, cr.top, cr.right, cr.bottom, SWP_SHOWWINDOW );
```

This code comes from Microsoft website...

pHdr->hWndTab is the window handle for the tab control

pHdr->hWndDisplay is the window handle for the content window of the current tab

EDIT: Actually, after clicking the lower tabs, the upper tabs move to the top of control...however, they are still blocked by the content window...

Comment: `TCM_ADJUSTRECT` definitely takes multiple rows of tabs into account. Can you post a screenshot to illustrate the actual problem you're seeing?

Comment: @JonathanPotter you're right AdjustRect works the problem is the OffsetRect() function that comes afterwards...I can't post a screenshot but after AdjustRect() the rect is correct...it moves the 'top' of the rect down 22 units...then OffsetRect() moves the 'top' up 20 units( 2 - 22 = -20 )...What is the proper method of resizing a tab control window?

Comment: Well why are you doing `OffsetRect` at all? The coords returned by `TCM_ADJUSTRECT` should be all that you need.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I am using code from [ Microsoft ]( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298366%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ) that shows how to resize the content window during a tab selection change...i fixed problem by using AdjustRect() after offsetting...see below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adjusting the display rectangle after offsetting:

```
typedef struct tag_dlghdr
{
    HWND hWndTab;
    HWND hWndDisplay;
    RECT rcDisplay;
    DLGTEMPLATE *apRes[ MAX_PAGES ];
    DLGPROC     MsgProc[ MAX_PAGES ]; 
}DLGHDR

Resize( HWND hWndDlg )
{    
    DLGHDR *pHdr = ( DLGHDR * )GetWindowLong( hWndDlg, GWL_USERDATA );

    DWORD dwDlgBase = GetDialogBaseUnits();
    int cxMargin = LOWORD( dwDlgBase ) / 4;
    int cyMargin = HIWORD( dwDlgBase ) / 8;
    m_niCurTabSel = TabCtrl_GetCurSel( pHdr->hWndTab );

    RECT cr;
    GetClientRect( pHdr->hWndTab, &cr );
    TabCtrl_AdjustRect( pHdr->hWndTab, FALSE, &cr ); 
    OffsetRect( &cr, cxMargin - cr.left, cyMargin - cr.top );
    CopyRect( &pHdr->rcDisplay, &cr );
    TabCtrl_AdjustRect( pHdr->hWndTab, FALSE, &pHdr->rcDisplay );
    SetWindowPos( pHdr->hWndDisplay, 0, pHdr->rcDisplay.left, pHdr->rcDisplay.top, pHdr->rcDisplay.right, pHdr->rcDisplay.bottom, SWP_SHOWWINDOW );

}
```